# Pass autopopulated data to another PHP page

Tags: javascript, php

How can I pass autopopulate data in this form to budget.php? I have been trying to use POST but it cannot pass what has been autopopulated. It only pass what user types in this form **Ref No:** and **Distance** BUT not what is populated on dropdown selection

```
                        <form action="budget.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="budget" onsubmit="return validateForm()" align="center">

                            <style>
                            form input { padding: 3px; }
                            </style>
                                <div align="center">
                                    <p><u><strong>Kindly enter the Trip ID.</u></strong></p>
                                    <table border=1 cellpadding=2 rows=1>
                                    <form name="budget">
                                    Ref No:<br />
                                    <input name="refno" type="text" class="ed" /><br />
                                     Distance:<br />
                                    <input name="distance" type="text" id="distance" class="ed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /><br />
                                     Fuel Cost/Litre<br/>
                                    <input name="fuelcostperl" type="text" id="fuelcostperl" class="ed" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /><br />
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <u><strong><align = "left"/>Please Enter the Trip No:/ID to Calculate the budget</strong>
                                    <tr><td>Trip No:</label></td><td><input type='text' name='req_id' id="req_id" size=20 onchange="updateBudget()">
                                    <td>Drop Date:</td><td><input type='text' id='dropdate' disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Initials:</td><td><input type='text' id='init' disabled="disabled"/></td>
                                    <div id="GetInformation">
                                    <td>Destination:</td><td><input type='text' id='destination' disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type='text' id='fname' disabled="disabled "/>
                                    <td>Number Of Persons:</td><td><input type='text' id='no_persons' disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Othernames:</td><td><input type='text' id='othernames' disabled="disabled"/>
                                    <td>Vote:</td><td><input type='text' id='vote'/disabled="disabled"></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Email Address:</td><td><input type='text' id='email' disabled="disabled"/>
                                    <td>Trip Purpose:</td><td><input textarea id='tripreason' disabled="disabled"/></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>Trip Date:</td><td><input type='text' id='tripdate'disabled="disabled"/>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr></tr>
                                    <tr></tr>

                            <script>
                            var ajax = getHTTPObject();

                                    function getHTTPObject()
                                    {
                                        var xmlhttp;
                                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                                          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                                          // code for IE6, IE5
                                          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                        } else {
                                          //alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
                                        }
                                        return xmlhttp;
                                    }

                                    function updateBudget()
                                    {
                                        if (ajax)
                                        {
                                            var reqValue = document.getElementById("req_id").value;
                                            if(reqValue)
                                            {
                                                var url = "populatebudget.php";
                                                var param = "?req_id=" + escape(reqValue);

                                                ajax.open("GET", url + param, true);
                                                ajax.onreadystatechange = handleAjax;
                                                ajax.send(null);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }


                                    function handleAjax()
                                    {
                                        if (ajax.readyState == 4)
                                        {
                                            budgetarr = ajax.responseText.split(",");

                                            var init = document.getElementById('init');
                                            var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
                                            var othernames = document.getElementById('othernames');
                                            var email = document.getElementById('email');
                                            var tripdate = document.getElementById('tripdate');
                                            var dropdate = document.getElementById('dropdate');
                                            var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
                                            var no_persons = document.getElementById('no_persons');
                                            var vote = document.getElementById('vote');
                                            var tripreason = document.getElementById('tripreason');

                                            init.value = budgetarr[0];
                                            fname.value = budgetarr[1];
                                            othernames.value = budgetarr[2];
                                            email.value = budgetarr[3];
                                            tripdate.value = budgetarr[4];
                                            dropdate.value = budgetarr[5];
                                            destination.value = budgetarr[6];
                                            no_persons.value = budgetarr[7];
                                            vote.value = budgetarr[8];
                                            tripreason.value = budgetarr[9];

                                        }
                                    }
                            </script>
                                    </table>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        function showUser(str){
                                            if (str == "") {
                                                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                                                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                                                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                            }
                                            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                                                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                                            }
                                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getdriver.php?q=" + str, true);
                                            xmlhttp.send();
                                        }
                                    </script>
```

Comment: I am trying to pass autopopulated data when I type textbox it auto populate other related fields. I then choose another drop down it populates other fields from a different Mysql table. How can I pass these data to a new phpform now that I have populate all in current phpform? @MarcoMura

Comment: I made a painful attempt format the code provided, but I'm still not 100% sure what you're asking. You basically want a typeahead, right? (On a side note, while editing I found that a tag at the label for the trip ID, `</ul>` is missing. You also misplaced a tag within a tag in a few spots)

Comment: @Winter I just wanted to know how i Can pass autopopulated data to another PHP form.I could only pass user entry textbox **Ref** and **distance** but I cant pass autopopulated data.

Comment: @Winter Thanks in advance for your patience. I have tried to summarise what I seek assistance of

Comment: put what you change (with autopopulated) in a hidden field in the form

Comment: @Winter I have not able to pass this data yet.

Comment: This question is very hard for us to try and solve considering we have no idea what you mean by "Autopopulated data." I'm assuming it has something to do with the HttpRequests being called.

Comment: OK.When `req_id` is entered on text box it autofill other text boxes on this page with variables related to that `req_id` using HttpRequests. My question is, How can I transfer value in these text boxes to another page. Thank you.